# Integrating node js into cordova mobile application (Connecting the mobile app to the server)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, jquery-mobile, express

I am working on a mobile web application(hybrid app) project built with Cordova, Jquery Mobile and AngularJS. The front end pages are already finished. My problem now lies on connecting the app to the server (i'm planning to use Node.JS/Express by the way).

My keypoints of confusion are these :

1. How do i structure my application? Do i place my node js files inside my cordova app directory? So currently, this is my cordova application's directory. Do i just place the node js files on the root directory?

Mobile App Directory

```
-www
-hooks
-platform
-plugins
-config.xml
-server (Do i place the node js files here perhaps?)
```

2. Assuming,that i've already integrated node, when i run the application in my mobile phone, will node still run? Or how do i run the server? Do you have any advice? This is the part where i get total blackness. Because i have no idea. I have read of having to host node in a server, but please help on at least the basic thing i should do.

If you could give me some existing examples, where in they used node as a back end, that would also be great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run your node server side app on a server, for example AWS. This code will have API endpoints where you can connect to with your mobile app. e.g.:

/API/profile

As you are you are using Angular in your mobile app you can make a GET request with angular to retrieve the data you need.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

This setup can be used for all the data you need in the app. With different end points off course.

Maybe this helps:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/12/votr-part-5-angularjs-crud-restful-apis.html

Even though it is not a mobile app but the concept is the same. All the front end angular code can be used in your mobile app

Comment: Ah, so that's how i connect to the server. So for example, i could use $http.get('awserver.com/api') to fetch data from my server, right?

Comment: Hi Roselle, Yes that is how you can GET info from your server into your mobile app.